# How to reset CSS background gradient

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the gradient background color of the caption on my Vaadin panel.

My custom theme extends `Valo` and I want a flat background (for the CAPTION) and a white font.  I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
.v-panel-caption {
  background-color: #157FCC;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

On my panel, the font is white like I want but the background is still the grey gradient background.

How do I remove that gradient? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS background gradient works similarly to background image, to reset that you'll need to set `background: none #color;`.

Example:

```
.v-panel-caption {
  background: none #157FCC;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

gradient is the same thing as an image

```
.v-panel-caption {
    background-image: none;

}
```